# How to run events sequentially in C# or Similar Frameworks

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

How to Cancel/Regulate event which is executing in parallel with same event in another thread.

For e.g. In a textbox, every time we enter a character the event fires if text changed event is defined. But after entering first character, the event (Let us call First Event) takes lot of time (as there will be more strings which match a single character), and does some action like changing content of a title label. And after entering a second character the new event which raised to run in parallel takes less time. So now, the second event which fired after entering second character executes fast and returns first and first event executes last and thus, first event's result will be printed ultimately on the label rather than the second one.

Is there a better way to cancel the first event before starting the second event. One thing that comes to my mind is to register threads on a global list variable and kill all threads which are not dead before starting your execution. Will this work?? Any better way to handle this situation.

P.S. I know that search could be initiated after a space or enter to solve this particular issue. But I think you have already noticed my main point. :)

Comment: I'd look into [Reactive Extensions](https://rx.codeplex.com/) to manipulate event streams, along with Task Parallel Library...

Comment: Since UI is monothread events are always sequenced by their own.

Comment: @FelicePollano but not necessarily the result of the callback that is initiated by the event.

Comment: For example, if the user types "abc", but your client has cached the search result for "abc" but not "ab", then the UI could update with the results of "abc", followed by the results for "ab". Not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favourite library for dealing with this exact problem is `Rx.Net` with `TPL`. This behaviour can be easily implemented with a combination of a Cancellable Task with an event observer using `Observable.FromAsync`

Some code!

```
var textChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern(x => textBox.TextChanged += x, x => textBox.TextChanged -= x)
                        .Select(_ => textBox.Text);
IDisposable eventHandler = textChanged.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                              .Select(text => Observable.FromAsync((TaskCancelationToken cancel) => DoSearchTaskAsync(text, cancel)))
                              .Switch()
                              .Subscrible(results =>
                              {
                                  //Update the UI
                              });
```

Note there is no need to explicitly type any of this...I am only doing it for clarity, but I am more than likely to have mistyped a class name or two...

EDIT

The Search method would be the method body of `Task<TReturn> DoSearchTaskAsync(string, TaskCancellationToken)`.

The magic sauce comes from the `Observable.FromAsync` and `Observable.Switch`.

Each time we have a change in the textBox.Text we fire an event. That is filtered by the `.Throttle` (as you would expect). The clever bit is when we then create a new event source on `DoSearchTaskAsync` using `Observable.FromAsync`. At this point we have an `IObservable<IObservable<TResult>>`, or another way to put it, an eventsource of an eventsource. The switch means we only want the results from the most recently sent eventsource from the outter eventsource, and kill (Dispose) the subscription of previous eventsources.

The act of disposing the previous `Observable.FromAsync` will cause the `TaskCancellationToken` to cancel, and prevent its results bubbling up, whilst we subscribe to the new `Task`.

All very clever stuff, and I only recently came across this AWESOME pattern (I would credit the author if I could).

As for the `Observable.FromEventPattern` that is pretty unfortunate, as of C#5, there are no first class eventhandlers, so we pass in a lambda for subscription and a lambda for de-subscription.

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, can you please explain me the code?? I am a little new to  this stuff. Thanks in advance.. Things I'm looking for is, 
1. where to bind this event??
2. Where is my Search operation Method is called?( **DoSearchTaskAsync** ??)
3. And How does it Cancel Previous Events which are called already?? It needs to have a reference to those methods right??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I just saw your edit... after a refresh :) Thanks :)

Comment: @sriharshaKB I did edit my answer. Its the best I can do. Unfortunately, you need a good grounding in Rx.Net before you can understand what I've written as the explaination.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET `Task` API has the concept of cancellation built in.  See this page for an example and links to more information. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I thought of that..But I just mentioned Threads solution because both are similar. Well I know Not Completely. But in a way, we are handling the issue with our own hands. Any other solutions?? And the built in cancellation has to be invoked some how. Then can we bind it to a variable saying that if it is false then stop execution. In that case, we can bind a task to that variable. WHen the next character comes, event fires and the variable will be set to false triggering end of all tasks.. then we later set it to true again and bind new task to that variable again. Sounds like _Sci-fi_?? :)